# AJAX Success function not being called after PyMongo query in Flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, pymongo

AJAX call here:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/join_game",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        player_name: name,
        game_code: code
    }, null, '\t'),
    success:function(response) {
        response_json = JSON.parse(response);
        if (response_json[0]) {
            alert(response_json[1]);
            alert(response_json[2]);
        } else {
            alert("That code is not valid.");
        }
    }
})
```

Flask block with PyMongo query here:

```js
@app.route("/join_game", methods=["POST"])
def join_game():
    player_name = request.json["player_name"]
    game_code = request.json["game_code"]

    code_query = {"game_code": game_code}
    if app.db.players.find_one(code_query):
        data = [True, player_name, game_code]
    else:
        data = [False]
    return json.dumps(data)
```

The data from the AJAX call gets sent to the Flask block and I can retrieve it successfully. The PyMongo query works exactly how I want it to. After the "return json.dumps(data)", the success function in the AJAX call should work, and I should see the appropriate alerts, but I'm not getting anything. If I get rid of the PyMongo query, then the success function works. Any idea why this is?

Edit:

I've also tried this syntax for the AJAX call, which isn't working either, but in another project I have been able to get it to work this way:

```js
function joinGame(form) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const name = form.player_name_guest.value;
        const code = form.game_code.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/join_game",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                player_name: name,
                game_code: code
            }, null, '\t'),
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(1);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Console is blank, but I added an error function (missing in the above snippet), and the code in the error function triggered. Not sure what the error is though. I'm also getting "200" status in the terminal from Flask.

Comment: console.log the 3 arguments of the error function

Comment: Assuming the 3 arguments are (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown). jqXHR.status gives 0, jqXHR.statusText gives "error". textStatus gives "error". errorThrown is blank. All of these were alerts. Console.log did not show anything in the console for these.

Comment: Check the network tab and investigate the request, look for anything thats odd

Comment: There isn't much to see in the network tab, and none of it looks out of the ordinary to me.